# Number/s rejected as invalid when Direct=True

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

My ctl file:

```
OPTIONS (ERRORS=50000000, SKIP=1, DIRECT=true )
LOAD DATA
 INFILE '\\*****path******\TAT_OUTPUTS\AMINET\1\1.csv'
 BADFILE'\\********path***********\1_BAD.csv'
 DISCARDFILE'\\***********path************\1_DSC.csv'
 TRUNCATE INTO TABLE MY_TABLE
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
 TRAILING NULLCOLS
(A , B, ....
```

My input csv file looks like

```
A|B
test|0
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table MY_TABLE, column B.
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

If I remove the `DIRECT=true` flag from the ctl file options. I am not getting the above error. I need DIRECT flag and so can't remove it.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you do a `desc my_table`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you're doing... can you actually re-create the error with the provided data and ctl file? I suspect there's something in your data you're not telling us about - or your ctl file given the `....`.